# Upgrade from Elmah 1.2.2 to Elmah.MVC 2.1.2 Result in "Elmah.ErrorSignal" not found?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, elmah.mvc

Previously i have  Elmah 1.2 and this function was working fine

```
 Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
```

I decide to upgrade to Elmah.MVC 2.1.2 and below method is not working anymore.

```
 Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
```

I have added reference of new Elmah.MVC in my project.But it is still not working.
did i need to use both to work?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to reference both ELMAH and Elmah.MVC. Elmah.MVC doesn't replace ELMAH.

Comment: Thanks i have done the same and its work.